# How do I use ">" and "<" inside "Cases" Mathematica function?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, pattern-matching

How do I use ">" and "<" inside "Cases" Mathematica function?

E.g., I would like the cases which end in something greater than 2 for the following nested list:

```
    lst = { {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1,1,4} }
```

I would like to do something like

```
    Cases[lst, {_, _,>2} ]
```

What it is the correct way to express ">2" above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straightforward fix to your approach is probably

```
Cases[lst, {_, _, x_ /; x > 2}]
```

See the documentation for `/;` or `Condition`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively,

```
Cases[lst, {_, _, _?(# > 2 &)}]
```